# Jquery thumbnail zoom

Tags: jquery, css, image-processing

I am looking to create swatches of clothes that pertains to the color, I will be using this as the base

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager7.html

Note the thumbnails on the page above, what I need to do is have the thumbnails not actually be shrunk down to the full size image, but just show a thumbnail of the center of the image without it being shrunk. This will ensure that the swatch (thumbnail) will better depict the color of the clothing.

Any ideas on what I could do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the [CSS clip property](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/).